# Unable to import standard libs to header files in native android project

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk

I'm trying to compile a PC C++ project to android.
I compiled the template example and it's working just fine also on my device.

At first, I created just a simple header file, but I cant import simple standard libraries, such as:
`#include <string>`

**The odd** thing is that if I change it to a **cpp** file, everything is imported just fine.

This is what I've done:

CMakeList.txt

```
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Werror")
# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

# now build app's shared lib

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        native-lib

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED
        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        native-lib.cpp
        BoolPair.h
        )

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
        log-lib

        # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
        # you want CMake to locate.
        log)

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        native-lib

        # Links the target library to the log library
        # included in the NDK.
        ${log-lib})
```

app build.gradle

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
                cppFlags += "-std=c++11"

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "I created just a simple header file, but I cant import simple standard libraries, such as: `#include <string>` ... if I change it to a cpp file, everything is imported just fine." - So whether the code you show works or doesn't work? If it works, why do you show it and what do you want from us? If it doesn't work, please show the **exact error message** you got.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't specified which language you want to support in your CMake file. The common CMake idiom is to specify a [`project()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html) call at the top of your file, which can optionally specify the target language:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
project(MyProjectName CXX)
```

When a language is *not* specified, CMake enables both C and C++ languages by default.

It is unclear how you were able to add only a `.h` file to your target `native-lib`. This typically results in a CMake error:

```
CMake can not determine linker language for target
```

Regardless, in your case, it appears CMake chose a C compiler because the language was not *explicitly* specified. With a C compiler, `#include <string>` is not supported.

On the other hand, by including a `.cpp` file along with the header, CMake now determines this is C++ source code based on the file extension. In this case, a C++ compiler is used and `<string>` is accepted.

Comment: "Thus, when you only include a `.h` file, CMake determines this is C code" - CMake doesn't differentiate header files and other non-source files. Without any source file specified for a library CMake should emit an error about not detecting the language for link.

Comment: @Tsyvarev You are correct. I just tested this on my machine, so not sure how the OP was able to produce this behavior. I still believe the C compiler was being used, when C++ actually should have been specified. I'll update the answer wording.